# Heroku and sendgrid - how to get it wired together now?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sendgrid

Some time back I set up a Ruby-onRails app with sendgrid and heroku.
I followed a tutorial where I had to:

- Set Credentials for Sendgrid via the webpage (herokuapp > sendgrid addon > settings > Credentials)
- Set SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENGRID_PASSWORD as environment variables in heroku.
- Refer to the SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD in my rails application.

Fine. Or so I thought.
Now I'm setting up a new app, and sendgrid has removed the "Credentials".

I have a gut feeling something is being created automatically for me, but how can I get my fingers on it and tie it together with my code? 
Are there some magic environment variable already available for me that I shall rather use in my code?

When I look at (the web) herokuapp > sendgrid add-on > Settings > Account details I see that there is a username and a password that is automatically generated, but how can I see what that auto-created password is so that I can get it into a heroku ENV variable?

Thanks for any help - I feel a bit lost here...

Answer (score 7):

You do the same thing. Every app has its own add-ons. They are not shared. If you have a new app you have to repeat what you did with your previous app:

1. go to your resources page and add your sendgrid add-on.
2. This creates your credentials under Settings > Config Variables. There should be SENDGRID_USERNAME and SENDGRID_PASSWORD
3. Generate your API key on Sendgrid's site and then add it to your Config Variables (Settings > Config Variables).

Finally setup your SMTP settings in your Rails app and you are done.

## How to setup Sendgrid on Heroku:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid#provisioning-the-add-on

## How to setup SMTP on Rails:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/Integrate/Frameworks/rubyonrails.html

Comment: Thanks! I guess the mess started when I automatically went on to sedtting the SENDGRID_* environment variables after creating the addon, hence overwriting the "correct" and autocreated variabeles. I removed the addon and re-added it and then things are working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to go into your Sendgrid dyno. Navigate to Settings>API Keys.

2.Click on create API Key, at the time of writing this it is a blue button in the top right corner of the page.

3.copy the key that they generate for you and paste it somewhere on your local machine, also navigate back to your heroku page. Navigate to your app's Settings and click on "reveal config variables". You should now see key value pairs of all the environment variables. In the Key column add "SENDGRID_API_KEY" and in the value column add the key that you copied from the Sendgrid website. Then use a ruby function that gets the SENDGRID_API_KEY.